# Is there a way to set content length of post request?

Tags: spark-java

I'm using the Spark web framework

[Spark](https://github.com/perwendel/spark)

I need to increase the limit of the request

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Spark API you can only set the content length for the response (package spark, class Response, method header()).
In Jetty you can set the attribute *org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize* ([Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-form-size.html)) and change the limit of the form.
Currently it's not possible to change directly the Jetty settings through Spark, however there is an open issue in github ([issue](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/314)) to solve this problem.

**Update**

Now it's possible to configure the Jetty server ([source](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/813)).

Comment: So what's the default size? This is sort of a security issue don't you think?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not using Spark during the last two years. However, i see in Github that Jetty server is now tunable (https://github.com/perwendel/spark/pull/813). There is also a useful discussion about maxFormContentSize (https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/1070)